# Aligning footer text in BS4 ekko-lightbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align the text in an [ekko-lightbox](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#single-image) (BS4) `data-footer` to the left. It is defaulted to align right. The lightbox is built on the BS4's Modal and so the lightbox's `data-footer` property seems to become Modal's `modal-footer`. However, no matter what CSS classes I try to apply I can't seem to shift the footer text to the left. I've tried a range of things including a custom class written into a `<span>` around the footer text, and also a custom class that should affect any `modal-footer` inside the `ekko-lightbox` container. No Dice. Do you know a solution to this? Kind thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `modal-footer` is using flex box and has a `justify-content` set to `flex-end`. Change this to `flex-start` and your text will be aligned to the left.  It's basically starting the flex at the right of the container so the text appears to be justified right (while it's actually left aligned).

Attached is a screen snapshot of the change I made in the inspector which starts the flex at the left, visually accomplishing left justified text for your case.

**The code adjustment:**

```
.modal-footer {
   justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

**How it presents when altered to** `flex-start`

[image]

**How it presents unaltered.**

Notice that in both examples `text-align` is left.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! BTW - I think you meant to write a css modification to `.modal-footer` instead of `.modal-content` above, as I tried the content version and it didn't work, but `.modal-footer` worked great.